# How to construct different modules using Gap?

Tags: group-cohomology, gap

I want to calculate the cohomology of some space group using Gap, with the coefficient different $\mathbb{Z}$-modules corresponding to different group actions on $\mathbb{Z}$. For example, for the space group be $p4m$, there can be eight different actions on $\mathbb{Z}$, and I want to calculate the cohomology of all of them using Gap.

I can first calculate the resolution using Gap.

> R:=ResolutionSpaceGroup(SpaceGroupIT(2, 11), 9);

When the $\mathbb{Z}$-module corresponds to the trivial action of the space group, I can calculate the cohomology using the following syntax.

> List([0..8], x->Cohomology(HomToIntegers(R), x));

I can also calculate the cohomology of a different module defined by the function "Determinant".

> Zor:=GroupHomomorphismByFunction(SpaceGroupIT(2, 11), GL(1, Integers), x->[[Determinant(x)]]);
> C:=HomToIntegralModule(R, Zor);
> List([0..8], x->Cohomology(C, x));

But I do not know how to input the rest six modules.

Comment: The commands look as if you are not just using GAP itself, but one of its packages. It might help to indicate the names of these packages in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following GAP commands provide one possible answer to your question. But there may be smarter ways of performing your computation.

```
gap> G:=SpaceGroupIT(2,11);;                                                                                               
gap> G:=Image(IsomorphismPcpGroup(G));; #convert G to a pcp group so that we don't need to call Polymake software
gap> R:=ResolutionAlmostCrystalGroup(G,9);; #A resolution for G
gap> iso:=IsomorphismFpGroup(G);; #create an isomorphism from the pcp group G to an fp group F
gap> F:=Image(iso);;
gap> L:=LowIndexSubgroupsFpGroup(F,2);; #List all subgroups of F of index 2.
gap> Length(L); #This will be the number of homomorphisms G--> GL(1,Z)                                         
8
gap> #For example let's work with the second of these homomorphisms G-->GL(1,Z)                                          
gap> hom:=NaturalHomomorphismByNormalSubgroup(F,L[2]);; #This creates the homomorphism G --> G/L[2]
gap> fn:=function(x);
 if x=(1,2) then return [[-1]]; fi;
 return [[1]];
 end;;
gap> rho:=GroupHomomorphismByFunction(G,GL(1,Integers),x-> fn(Image(hom,Image(iso,x))));; #rho: G --> GL(1,Z)
gap> C:=HomToIntegralModule(R,rho);;
gap> Cohomology(C,1);
[ 2 ]
gap> Cohomology(C,2);
[ 2, 2 ]
gap> Cohomology(C,3);
[ 2, 2, 2, 2 ]
gap> Cohomology(C,4);
[ 2, 2, 2, 2, 4 ]
```